# need help my query select join with where condition

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT tb_pemesanan_detail.id_pemesanan
, tb_pemesanan_detail.id_produk
, tb_pemesanan_detail.qty
, tb_produk.harga_produk
, tb_pemesanan.nama_pemesan
, tb_pemesanan.id_meja
, tb_pemesanan.bayar as tagihan 
FROM tb_pemesanan_detail
,b_produk
,tb_pemesanan 
WHERE tb_pemesanan_detail.id_produk = tb_produk.id_produk 
and tb_pemesanan.id_pemesanan = tb_pemesanan_detail.id_pemesanan 
and id_pemesanan = 'TR000000018'
```

Comment: error : #1052 - Column 'id_pemesanan' in where clause is ambiguous

Answer (score 0):

You have id_pemesanan  in both tabkle but in where condition you don't assign the table name

```
    SELECT tb_pemesanan_detail.id_pemesanan
        , tb_pemesanan_detail.id_produk
        , tb_pemesanan_detail.qty
        , tb_produk.harga_produk
        , tb_pemesanan.nama_pemesan
        , tb_pemesanan.id_meja
        , tb_pemesanan.bayar as tagihan 
    FROM tb_pemesanan_detail ,tb_produk,tb_pemesanan 
    WHERE tb_pemesanan_detail.id_produk = tb_produk.id_produk 
    and tb_pemesanan.id_pemesanan = tb_pemesanan_detail.id_pemesanan 
    and tb_pemesanan_detail .id_pemesanan = 'TR000000018'
```

and a suggestion  you should not use the (old) implicit join sintax you should use an explicti join ,
and use also tablename alias eg:

```
SELECT a.id_pemesanan
    , a.id_produk
    , a.qty
    , b.harga_produk
    , c.nama_pemesan
    , c.id_meja
    , c.bayar as tagihan 
FROM tb_pemesanan_detail a 
INNER JOIN tb_produk b ON a.id_produk = b.id_produk 
INNER JOIN tb_pemesanan  c ON c.id_pemesanan = a.id_pemesanan 
WHERE  a.id_pemesanan = 'TR000000018'
```

Comment: @Strawberry   .. just a minute

Answer (score 0):

The last column is your issue

tb_pemesanan_detail is missing from the last column in your sql query.

id_pemesanan is ambiguous because it doesn't have a table reference prefixed to it.

Change id_pemesanan to tb_pemesanan_detail.id_pemesanan
Or tb_pemesanan.id_pemesanan